# JMeter 5.1 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - clear results does not help (did in 2.13)

Tags: java, jmeter

I've recently switched from 2.13 JMeter to 5.1. In 2.13 when java gave out of memory error, I clicked `Clear all` button and it helped. Now in 5.1 I've got error.

> ERROR:o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

After some runs and some data accumulated in view results tree, but clear button does not help - view results tree becomes empty but error persists and Java mission control shows heap have not been reduced. Could it be some incorrect JMeter config or?

ADDED: Thank you for heap size settings tips. It's for smoke (debug) runs, I know I can increase heap, the question is as stated about clear command behavior and possible difference between versions.

BTW, I've also tried do invoke GC `jcmd <pid as reported by task manager in windows> GC.run` as per [How do you Force Garbage Collection from the Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523837/how-do-you-force-garbage-collection-from-the-shell) - head was not reduced, which as I understand means JMeter does not release pointers to old java objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase your heap size in properties file.

```
# This is the base heap size -- you may increase or decrease it to fit your
# system's memory availability:
HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

Refer: https://martijndevrieze.net/2017/01/20/jmeter-tips-tricks-tip-7/

Answer (score 1):

You're violating at least [2 JMeter best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

1. You should use [command-line non-GUI mode to run your test](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. You [should not be using any listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/)

JMeter 5.1 comes with 1 GB heap by default, you can increase JVM heap size by setting `HEAP` [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), for example the following setting will increase the heap to 2 GB:

```
HEAP=-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M
```

Comment: It's for smoke (debug) runs, I know I can increase heap, the question is as stated about clear command behavior.