# How to force garbage collection from Shell in Go

Tags: go, garbage-collection

You can force garbage collection in java using `jcmd <pid> GC.run` as shown at this StackOverflow link: [How do you Force Garbage Collection from the Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523837/how-do-you-force-garbage-collection-from-the-shell) . I understand that forcing garbage collection is frowned upon, but I was wondering if there was a similar command for golang. Like this question, I would like know if garbage collection can be done from the command line instead of calling Runtime.GC().

Comment: No, you would need to set that up yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to run the GC from the command line. Think that your program is a standalone compiled version.
If you need to "force" the GC to run at certain times, I think you could use two formulas:

1. In your app, check the existence of a file with inotify. When the file appears, you run the GC
2. In your app, wait for a signal from the operating system (Linux), such as SIGUSR1, and run the GC. Then you send the signal from the console using:

   kill -10 pid

Where pid is the identifier of the running program as it appears in ps -aux